# If $f+f'<\varepsilon$, then $f'<\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and there exstis $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(x)+f'(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. Prove that $f'(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in (a,b)$.

These are my efforts:

$\bullet$ If $f(x)\ge 0$ then $f'(x)<\varepsilon$, so we just need to consider those $x$ such that $f(x)<0$.

$\bullet$ Consider $g(x)=f(x)\cdot e^x-\varepsilon\cdot e^x$ then $g$ decreases on $(a,b)$. If $f(c)<\varepsilon$, then $f(x)<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in [c,b]$.

$\bullet$ If $f(x_0)\ge \varepsilon$ for some $x_0$ then $f$ increases in some neighborhood of $x$.

I cannot completely solve it. Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) =- e^{-x}$. Then $f+f^\prime = 0$.

Comment: Isn't there a requirement that $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: @SubSevn yes. So what? (the claim is false without additional assumptions)

Comment: If $f + f' = 0$ doesn't that imply that $\epsilon = 0$? (edit: this is incorrect, the requirement was that $f + f' < \epsilon$)

Comment: Ah wait, sorry read it wrong!

Comment: but then, since $f^\prime(x)=-e^{-x}$, $f^\prime<0<\epsilon$, so you would need to have $f(x)=-e^{-x}$

Comment: @Brent yes, thank you. Fixed it. The claim remains wrong, though, without additional assumptions